# Where is "local copies" of pip?

Tags: python, pip

I need to install pip offline due to some restrictions. According to the instructions given in [official site](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html), I can use this:

`python get-pip.py --no-index --find-links=/local/copies`

I'm using CentOS, where does "local copies" come from? If it means the installation copy, where can I find it in a machine with pip installed?

Comment: Windows? try `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`. Python 2.7.9+ and 3.4+ both come with pip

Comment: Sorry, it's in linux.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: It's 2.7. Sorry, it's resolved, thank you.

Comment: Look into the folder with pip installed(for linux machine) /usr/lib/python2.7/Scripts/

Comment: @realjin: If you resolved the issue please post the answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My partner got the solution which is simple:

Just go to python package index site, download the latest pip source package(which is pip 7.1.0 now on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip/7.1.0) and install from source.